# Linux: create list of text with multiple operators

Tags: bash, perl, programming

I want to make a list like this:

```
7785237_770x770_de3b540dc13ed50023d17854513b40aa07e50a6a
732308_770x770_ec5c344c0114011a5306b31142ff9b001813f6d6
7430796_800x800_ec0f2e614e2dc460fca7e626d83073c827dc9130
7431018_800x800_7caa40b85c21485c64f2ad509a0d9cc1ed3ba526
```

So to explain:
First block before the first "_" is just a number between 0 and 9500000 - second block varies between two variables: "770x770" and "800x800"
Last block is a 40 character long HEX block.

So what I want to do, is to generate all possible combinations of these, and combine it into one line.

How do I do this? Don't know if it can be done in BASH, or it should be done in perl/something similar.

Comment: _all possible combinations of these_ you mean all possible combinations of 16**40*9500000*2 so 27768531109287155445870011821609377373462718316544000000 lines?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean. Also, it is more of finding a way to automate it.

Comment: It will not finish in your lifetime.  Or fit on your hard disk.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: You cannot generate a file containing 9500001*2*16^40 lines. That file would be something like a trillion (US) times the total size of all hard disks in the world. What are you trying to do? A 40-digit hex string looks like a SHA-1 hash; this kind of hash is designed so that you cannot find the right one unless you know what it's the hash of. If you're trying a brute-force search on an image server, forget it; you can't do it, by design.

Comment: @Gilles and Mikel: Just playing around with my box.

Comment: The FAQ says: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: I tested my script, with only 95 instead of 9500001 and 4 hex digits instead od 40 I got a 12M file :D

Comment: @Mikel: Well, i'd say it is practical and answerable - the script can be used for other than such a crazy thing as I tried :)

Comment: Why do you want to do that, specifically? All those combinations will generate about 10^55 different possibilities, and even all the hard drives in the planet will not be able do store those.

Comment: @FrederikNielsen If the ability to reasonably complete your task also implies the ability to brute-force 128-bit symmetric encryption and 160-bit hashes, then no I would not call it practical.  If you are or ever become a pointy-haired boss, I'd hate to be one of your employees ... :P

Comment: @jw013: Hahah, it was mainly for testing some performance on my box, so I found a image hosting site, and seeing if I could "mirror" their servers :)

Comment: @FrederikNielsen - Yeah, don't do that.

Comment: En excellent question with cycle on quite a complex task. But again question is closed for stupidity ih "boss" heads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess bash cannot handle those amounts and in case it could you'd get old before it sorts it out.

Python [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) can help you creating and assembling all combinations.

I suggest Python and not perl as this is more a math task rather than a text manipulation one.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

for x in combinations_with_replacement('0123456789abcdef', 40):
    h = ''.join(x)
    for y in xrange(9500001):
        for r in ("770x770", "800x800"):
            print "{0}_{1}_{2}".format(y, r, h)
```

Of course Python is way slower than C so don't expect best performances. On the other side don't expect to get the same result in C with only 5 lines of code.

Comment: Looks good Neurino. Now I just gotta figure out how I get the itertools to work on my centos box..

Comment: python is installed by default on most linux distributions, I think centOS does too. Anyway given it has no practical applications you may **not** want to save results to a file but simply create a function and let it `yield` instead of `print` results.

Comment: Yeah sounds about right, but centos comes with an old python as far as i can see. So trying to compile a newer one now. Anyhow, thanks for the piece of code :)

Comment: I get a syntax error on line 9, at the last " - says Invalid Syntax.. Is it my box thats acting strange, or is there something else wrong?

Comment: Works here with copy & paste.

Comment: Works for me on my other linux box too. Thanks! :)